# How to Generate class with JAXB from XSD with imports

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, xsd, jaxb

I have an XSD where use types of another XSDs , exemple:

```
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://www.tce.sp.gov.br/audesp/xml/tagcomum" version="1.0" xml:lang="pt-BR"
    xmlns:tag="http://www.tce.sp.gov.br/audesp/xml/tagcomum"
    xmlns:gen="http://www.tce.sp.gov.br/audesp/xml/generico"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:import namespace="http://www.tce.sp.gov.br/audesp/xml/generico"
    schemaLocation="../generico/AUDESP_TIPOSGENERICOS_2016_A.XSD"/>
```

How to make a JAXB code generator understand that a reference to another ?
my tentatives were frustrated by not filenotfound errors

Comment: Could you please share what you tried ? Also you must be aware that when you use XJC in Netbeans the `schemaLocation` is determined by your project root directory. So i can not start by `../` otherwise it means that your XSD is not inside your project directory.

Comment: Sure, the files are in different pastes , i have tried put in same paste, use complete path , associate on binding files , set Extensions checked , nv checked , both checked, on binding file set in path of  jaxb xml-paste xsd copy   but same error :IOException file not foud.

Comment: If you tried to put all your XSDs in the same directory with `schemaLocation="AUDESP_TIPOSGENERICOS_2016_A.XSD"` and it didn't work you might have another problem. Maybe permission issue.

Comment: using binding files  and select the file in same paste correct ?

Comment: No. It's two different things.

Comment: i put all files in same folder, but the Exception explain IOerror with path of generate JAXB  ,not the path of all files in folder